# How to check if certain values exist in a time window using Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have dataframe `df`. I want to check to see if there is any item that does not have code B during the past 6 days from its most recent record.

```
df=
item   Date    code
X   3/5/2016    A
X   3/6/2016    B
X   3/10/2016   A
X   3/12/2016   B
Y   3/5/2016    B
Y   3/7/2016    A
Y   3/9/2016    A
Y   3/10/2016   A
Z   3/4/2016    B
Z   3/9/2016    A
Z   3/10/2016   A
Z   3/13/2016   A

result = [Y,Z]
```

here is my attempt: I created a column to represent the check date. I groupby item, filter out old records, and say if there is no record with code B, keep it. But my code dosn't seem to do that! Any help is appreciated.

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
grouped = df.groupby('item')
df['check date'] = (grouped['Date2'].transform(lambda grp: grp.max()-pd.Timedelta(days=6)))
df2 = df.loc[(df['date2'] > df['check date'])]
result=pd.Series(df2['code']<>'B')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need add condition `(df['code'] != 'B')` with `and` (`&`) and then [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
grouped = df.groupby('item')
df['check date'] = (grouped['Date2'].transform(lambda grp: grp.max()-pd.Timedelta(days=6)))

df2 = df.loc[(df['Date2'] > df['check date']) & (df['code'] != 'B')]
print df2
   item       Date code      Date2 check date
2     X  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-06
5     Y   3/7/2016    A 2016-03-07 2016-03-04
6     Y   3/9/2016    A 2016-03-09 2016-03-04
7     Y  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-04
9     Z   3/9/2016    A 2016-03-09 2016-03-07
10    Z  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-07
11    Z  3/13/2016    A 2016-03-13 2016-03-07

print df2.item.unique()
['X' 'Y' 'Z']
```

Or if you need check if all values by groupby are not `B` use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Date2'] > df['check date'])]
print df2
   item       Date code      Date2 check date
2     X  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-06
3     X  3/12/2016    B 2016-03-12 2016-03-06
4     Y   3/5/2016    B 2016-03-05 2016-03-04
5     Y   3/7/2016    A 2016-03-07 2016-03-04
6     Y   3/9/2016    A 2016-03-09 2016-03-04
7     Y  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-04
9     Z   3/9/2016    A 2016-03-09 2016-03-07
10    Z  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-07
11    Z  3/13/2016    A 2016-03-13 2016-03-07

print df2.groupby('item').filter(lambda x: (x.code != 'B').all())
   item       Date code      Date2 check date
9     Z   3/9/2016    A 2016-03-09 2016-03-07
10    Z  3/10/2016    A 2016-03-10 2016-03-07
11    Z  3/13/2016    A 2016-03-13 2016-03-07

print df2.groupby('item').filter(lambda x: (x.code != 'B').all()).item.unique()
['Z']
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too. Thanks.